# Is there any way to get the document of DRF from old version?

Tags: django-rest-framework, version

Yes, I'm using DRF version 2.3.13 because of some reasons, so how to get docs for specific DRF version. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link to the old documentation is at the very top of the http://www.django-rest-framework.org homepage: http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/

Comment: The link to the DRF 2 docs doesn't seem to be at the top of the homepage anymore. Also, what if I want to see the docs for DRF 3.4? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: clone the repository, checkout the tag, install the deps (requirements/requirements-testing.txt & requirements/requirements-documentation.txt)  and build the documentation (mkdocs build)

Comment: @Ariel No 3.4, but maybe 3.6 will be close enough for your needs. https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-rest-framework-old-docs/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for version 2, but versions 3.9.0, 3.8.2, 3.7.7, and 3.6.4
are available [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-rest-framework-old-docs/)